# OCR software for Linux

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, ocr

I am looking for OCR software to digitalize scans. Some are prints, some are hand-written (like [this](https://martin-thoma.com/images/2017/02/scan-thoma-1-1-statistik.jpg)). I want to have an easier time finding documents. So I want to generate one text file for each image (of a few hundred images).

Online services are OK, but I prefer offline software. Python libraries are also OK.

### Requirements

- Works on [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu)
- Is free as in beer ([gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis))

### What I've tried

- http://www.onlineocr.net/: Does not work at all with handwriting, Does not recognize tables (tested with [this file](https://github.com/MartinThoma/morc/blob/master/morc-data/morc-3-1.jpg))
- http://www.free-ocr.com/: Same problem as http://onlineocr.net
- ocrfeeder: Crappy results (tested with the same image as before). As it uses tesseract internally, I don't think I have to try tesseract.
- GOCR: Same as ocrfeeder
- Tesseract: `tesseract morc-data/morc-3-1.jpg out.txt -l deu` - same as ocrfeeder

Comment: I've not found anything perfect yet either. But in the repositories, you also find Cuneiform and Tesseract which you could give a try. I had slightly better results with Cuneiform, but that might well depend on the source used. The hand-written stuff you'll probably have to "OCR by hand and eyes", unfortunately. // Oh: I confirm your results on GOCR and ocrfeeder. Wasn't satisfied by them at all. And a hint for better results: Make the images bigger. Really helps, even if only "upscaled".

Comment: Recognizing hand-written mathematical notation is a very difficult problem, and I doubt any software currently exists to do it accurately.

Comment: @Kodiologist: I guess so, too. But also the second image doesn't work at all (tables).

Comment: @MartinThoma Tesseract is probably the best free (libre) OCR software, and I think it can cope with tables. I don't know if it supports German.

Comment: German supported in Tesseract since v.3

Comment: @Kodiologist It clearly cannot cope with the table in the image I provided.

Comment: Your hand written sample is made worse by being largely mathematical notation - that is harder still.

Answer (score 1):

The best free online OCR service is https://ocr.space - they have a free tier of 25,000 conversions per month and a very good recognition rate.

That said, like all the other free services, it does not detect and preserve tables. The only service that I know that does this well is Abbyy, a commercial solution.

Handwriting: I am not aware of any service that works well with handwriting.

Comment: "very good recognition rate" - how was that evaluated? Or are you only relying on gut feeling?

Comment: Yeah, I should add: I tested all the free services mentioned so far. Ocr.space had the best recognition rate for *my* use case, which is OCR on memes and movie subtitles, like the one you see here: http://fuckyeahsubtitles.tumblr.com  ...here are their own test cases: https://ocr.space/blog/2015/02/ocr-online-converter-review.html

Answer (score 0):

OCR.Space, which was recommended in another answer, I found to work better than Google Docs for most documents, however neither OCR.Space nor Google Docs can properly scan tables. They can scan the text, but the original table formatting is lost.

Proper scanning of tables requires an application that can output an OCR scan as formatted text. [Free Online OCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/) allows the user to download a properly formatted OCR scan in either .doc or .rtf formats, as well as .txt and .pdf.